# ECMA6 spread parameters in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I see a reactjs sample code written as,

```
var App = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
      <div className='content'>
            <RouteHandler {...this.state} />
      </div>
      </div>
      )
   }
})
```

This is the part that confuses me.

```
        <RouteHandler {...this.state} />
```

In this, `RouteHandler` custom element uses `...`. And ECMA6 functions with splat/rest params use triple dots in their function definitions. So, why does the people use `...` during function invocation (or) on the application side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the rest operator but the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), applied to JSX attributes. 
See [JSX Spread Attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html).

`<RouteHandler {...this.state} />` is equivalent to `React.createElement(RouteHandler, Object.assign({}, this.state))`.

Note that the Object spread and rest operators the JSX spread attributes feature is inspired from are not a part of the ES6 specification. There is [a stage 1 proposal](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) to include them in ES7. In the meantime, you can already use them by passing the `--harmony` option to the JSX compiler CLI, or the `--stage 1` option to the [babel](https://babeljs.io/) CLI.

Comment: You should clarify that this is not the normal ES6 spread operator, but a JSX feature that makes it work on objects